# Showing the vector is in the kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces, and that $f:V \to W$ is a linear map. Suppose also that $u$ and $v$ are vectors in $V$ such that $f(u)=f(v)$. Show that there is a vector $w \in \ker f $ such that $v=u+w$.

I roughly understand what is kernel and its definition but I have no idea how to apply it to this question particularly the $f(u)=f(v)$ and $v=u+w$ part. Is it something to do with zero vectors? I don't understand how to show this.

Comment: What is $f(v-u)$?

Comment: Try $w=v-u$; it satisfies $v=u+w$ "for free", now just show that $w\in \ker f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have: $$f(u) = f(v)$$
$$f(v) - f(u) = 0$$
$$f(v-u) = 0$$
$$f(w) = 0$$

And if you know the definition of kernel, it just follows from there.

Comment: why is f(v)-f(u) = f(v-u)? can we assume that immediately?

Comment: Since f is a linear map, by definition f(u + v) = f(u) + f(v).

Answer (score 1):

We has necessarily:
$w - v-u$, let us check that it is in $\ker f$.

Using linearity:
$f(w) = f(v-u) = f(v) - f(u) = 0$
That's it.